# Why does the HP Procurve show MAC addresses as 64bit and what do the first 16bits represent?

Tags: vlan, hp-procurve

I'm working on an HP ProCurve 1810G running software P1.17.
When I look at the MAC address table, it shows the learned MACs as 64bit addresses.  Closer examination shows that the last 6 octets are the actual MAC, the first two are something else.

The manual just shows the page as I see it, with no explanation.

Do you know what these additional two octets represent?

Comment: More work shows that the second octet is the VLAN of the learned MAC.  The first octet (so far) has always been 02.

Comment: I suppose it could be that it is prepared for the protocols that _do_ use 64-bit MAC addresses.

Comment: Prepending the VLAN does makes sense since a MAC address is only relevant for the VLAN on which it is seen.

Comment: If there's a vlan ID in there, it's probably 12 bits (for 4096 VLANs) wide, not just 8 bits; that leaves 4 bits for "something else"

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

P1.17 is ancient (March 2010). Our 1810Gs - v1 and v2 - show MAC addresses as 48 bit. I'd update the firmware; P2.23 is latest for v1.

If you do need an answer to what the two additional octets represent we'd need to know what they look like - as probably no one's running P1.17 any more. If guessing wasn't off-topic here my bet would be on the VLAN ID (with the unused 4 bits zeroed).